# How to make column sorting false using UI component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

make column sorting false using UI component in magento2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to make UI component sorting false
Add tag  in your UI component

```
<column name="email">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Email</label>
        <sortable>false</sortable>
        <fieldClass>
            <class name="long-text-field">true</class>
        </fieldClass>
    </settings>
</column>
```